# is it possible using javascript to delete this hidden Zugo Flash movie on my page

Tags: javascript, flash, spyware

The following hidden Flash movie is appearing on pages I am coding; until I figure out how to remove it from my system, is it possible using javascript to find it and delete it?  Its container's id might change.

```
<div id="SiUnhdqlqHN9t7wB_tbstore_container" 
        style="left:-2000px; top:-2000px; position:absolute;">
    <param name="movie" value="http://tbupdate.zugo.com/ztb/2.5/jsi/man/fc.swf"/>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
```

Comment: I would not rely on javascript to prevent it from being there - take your server down and fix the actual problem; anything else is irresponsible.

Comment: It is on my development PC which has Microsoft Security running on it.

Comment: If it's only affecting you you could just add an entry for zugo in your hosts file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't spend time on workarounds. Stop everything and find out why this is happening, and when you find it, squash it flat.**

Having said that, if I assume the `param` elements are within the `div` and that the `div` doesn't contain anything else, then:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var index;
var div;
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    div = list[index];
    if (div.id.indexOf("store_container") !== -1) {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
        break;
    }
}
```

Or if you're using a browser with `querySelector`, it's a **lot** easier because you can use the [attribute ends with selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings):

```
var div = document.querySelector("div[id$=store_container");
if (div) {
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

But again: **Much** more important to spend time fixing the actual problem, not on workarounds.

Comment: Thanks.  Went into registry and zapped everything containing Zugo or StartNow and uninstalled ToolbarUpdater.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to JQuery:

```
$('div').each(function(){
  if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf("_tbstore_container") != -1) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```